# Dias da semana dinamicamente

Tags: php

Quero mostrar os dias da semana (Terça 2 dezembro) numa tabela por semana a partir da função date. Ou seja a tabela tem 7 colunas e começa no domingo até sabado. Por exemplo:

```
<td>Dia da semana</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uso da função [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) do PHP para obter o dia da semana.

```
echo date("l"); //exibe o nome do dia da semana, em inglês
echo date("N"); //exibe a representação numérica do dia da semana

echo date("d")." "; //exibe o dia
echo date("m")." "; //exibe o mês
echo date("Y")." "; //exibe o ano
```

Como parâmetro você passa o formato de saída desejado ("N" retorna a representação numérica ISO-8601 do dia da semana)

Usando `date("N")` é possível construir uma função simples que retorne o dia da semana em português.

```
echo dayOfWeek(date("N")); //exibe o dia da semana em portugues

function dayOfWeek($day){
    switch ($day) {
        case 1:
            return "Segunda";
        case 2:
            return "Terça";
        case 3:
            return "Quarta";
        case 4:
            return "Quinta";
        case 5:
            return "Sexta";
        case 6:
            return "Sábado";
        case 7:
            return "Domingo";
    }
}
```

Sobre a questão de gerar uma tabela com dos dias da semana...

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
for ($i=1; $i <= 7 ; $i++) { 
    echo "<td>";
    echo dayOfWeek($i);
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Certo e quero escrever o dia e o mes junto ao dia de semana.

Comment: mesmo esquema, só procurar na documentação qual parâmetro te retorna o número do mês